# Server-Side Paging for improve performance

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I followed the instruction of Pagination for Angular step by step in it's documentation that is here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination.
My pagination works perfect and I don't have any problem with that. However since I'm working with a large data-set - I don't want to work with the full collection in memory, and need some kind of server-side paging, where the server sends just a single page at a time. As mentioned in that article I should use `totalItems` parameter and use count, but I don't know how? How should I set the `total`?

```
<table class='table' *ngIf="collection">
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of collection | 
       paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total  }">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And my WEB API is like this:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> MyMethod()
{
    int perPage = 10;
    int start = (page - 1) * perPage;
    int end = start + perPage;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("externalAPI");
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType =
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<MyClass> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content);
        return data.Skip(start).Take(perPage).ToList();
    }
}
```

And:

```
p: number = 1;
total: number;

http.get('url', {
    params: {
        page : this.p
   }
}).subscribe(result => {
    this.collections = result.json() as Collection[];
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 2):

in order to paginate on the server side you need to have two things:

1. pageSize or *itemsPerPage* in your case
2. pageNumber which is basically your *currentPage*

You need to send these two values to your webapi so it knows what data to return.
They would become parameters to your action and you can then pass them through to webapi.

how you paginate in webapi, it depends on your code. If you use EntityFramework it's straight forward with Take and Skip methods. If you have a stored procedure ( so T-SQL ) you can do it with Fetch and Offset.

A word of caution on pageNumber. Page 1 on your UI needs to be become page 0 on the server side, so when your UI requests page 1 that is basically page 0 of the data. Page 2 UI side, becomes Page 1 data side, so you probably pass 
`pageNumber - 1` to the back end. Just keep this in mind.

totalItems is a number that comes from the back end. 
Let's say your web api returns paginated data which looks like this:

```
public class myReturnedData
{
    public string someData1 { get;set; }
    public string someData2 { get;set }
}
```

your api returns a list of this class basically.

At this point create another object which looks like this:

```
public class myPaginatedReturnedData
{
    public List<myReturnedData> { get; set; }

    public int TotalItemsCount { get; set; }
}
```

your front end has no way of knowing what the total count is since it only receives one page of data so you need to get that number back from the API and this is one way of doing it.

So before you paginate, on the server side, you do a total count of your items and then you paginate the data and finally send back both these items.

On the front end side, you will have pageSize, and totalItemsCount and you can use this to calculate how many page indexes you should display to the user.

If your pageSize is 10 and totalItemsCount is 55 then your page index will be from 1 to 6, with page 6 only showing 5 items. You can easily write a method, on the client side for this calculation.

<-- extra details -->

change this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> MyMethod()
```

to

```
public async Task<myPaginatedReturnedData> MyMethod()
```

I've basically changed your original returned class to the new one in my example which is a wrapper of yours plus the totalCount value.

This allows you to set the value in your front end since you are now returning it together with your actual paginated data.

On the client side, the response of the API will be a string.

You could parse the response string into a JSON object, using something like

```
var apiData = JSON.parse(responseString)
```

This gives you an object and you can access your data from there.

Comment: Good solution , but why sealed class ?

Comment: oh, you don't have to, it's just a habit of mine, to seal everything that is not meant to be extended. Don't do it if you don't need to.

Comment: It's ok , it was just a question ;)

Comment: it was a good question, I removed it as it creates other discussions not related to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have changed my code and add some code based on what you said and it's documentation. However I still have problem with front-end, I have almost done, just I don't know how should I set the total variable from client side. Please check my updated question.

Comment: I've added a bit more to my answer, changing the return type of your action to include to totalItems count property

Comment: Thanks but I'm fine with server part and now should I use a ViewModel as you have shown but I don't know how should I say `result.TotalItemsCount` in my front-end because it doesn't recognize `TotalItemsCount` and just `json()` method is available there!

Comment: added JSON.parse to the answer, for that part of the question.

Comment: Thanks again. How can I paginate in webapi since I'm using `HttpClient.GetAsync` to call an external API?? How should I use `Skip` and `Take` methods with `HttpClient.GetAsync`? For now my server side paging works, but every time it retrieves the JSON list from an external API then applies the `Skip` and `Take` methods over it and so I can't see any performance.

Comment: I asked a question about this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076579/use-linq-skip-and-take-methods-with-httpclient-getasync-method-for-improving-p