# Use LINQ (Skip and Take) methods with HttpClient.GetAsync method for improving performance?

Tags: c#, angular, linq, async-await

I have used the following code to retrieve the content of a JSON feed and as you see I have used the paging techniques and `Skip` and `Take` methods like this:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<myPaginatedReturnedData> MyMethod(int page)
{
    int perPage = 10;
    int start = (page - 1) * perPage;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("externalAPI");
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType =
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        IEnumerable<myReturnedData> data = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<myReturnedData>>(content);
        myPaginatedReturnedData datasent = new myPaginatedReturnedData
        {
            Count = data.Count(),
            myReturnedData = data.Skip(start).Take(perPage).ToList(),
        };
        return datasent;
    }
}
```

My paging works fine, however I can't see any performance improvement and I know this is because every time I request a new page it calls the API again and again **and after retrieving all contents, it filters it using `Skip` and `Take` methods**, I am looking for a way to apply the `Skip` and `Take` methods with my `HttpClient` so that it only retrieves the needed records for every page. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: if data fetch using httpClient is time taking operation - why not cache data and use in subsequent request ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal If I'd retrieved my data from a database I could use `Skip` and `Take` methods so that it just gives me only needed records, but I am looking for a way to apply the Skip and Take methods with my `HttpClient.GetAsync` method but I can't use these methods with `HttpClient.GetAsync`.

Comment: what is meant is to extract out this operation `IEnumerable<myReturnedData> data = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<myReturnedData>>(content);` to separate method and use cache (say InMemory Cache) to fetch data first time only. with this you can avoid making network call on for every subsequent request on server

Comment: @RahulAgarwal So you mean that isn't there anyway to only request and retrieve the needed records from that API? for caching It should retrieves all records for first time and if I want do this, I'd prefer to use Angular paging without server side paging and work with the full collection in memory.

Comment: I think in that case server returning json data should honor paging and skip.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Can you please show what's your mean with an answer with some explanation please?

Answer (score -1):

In order to apply the Take/Skip to the data retrieval, the server would have to know about them. You could do that with an IQueryable LINQ provider (see [1] for getting only an idea of how complex that is) or, better, by passing the appropriate values to the `client.GetAsync` call, something like

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + $"?skip={start}&take={perPage}");
```

Of course, **your server-side code has to interpret those `skip` and `take` parameters correctly; it's not automatic**.

You might also want to look at OData (see [2]), but I have never actually used it in production; I just know it exists.

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client

Comment: No. It still retrieves all records!

Comment: `client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + $"?skip={start}&take={perPage}")` server returning data need to embrace this OData specific protocol

Comment: @J.P -- you need to write code to interpret the skip / take arguments, or use OData to have something like them interpreted automatically.

Comment: OK but how should I do this?